# Analog PID and high power

Tags: operational-amplifier, power, pid-controller

I want to implement this analog PID controller to control the temperature of a boiler for a coffee machine. I have seen many tutorials on how to do this using digital PID temperature controllers plugged in directly to an outlet. Most boilers I have seen use around 1kW of power. However, the transistor configuration is not able to supply anywhere close to that amount. What would be the best way to regulate boiler temperature **using the op amp design in the picture**?

[image: Analog PID Controller]

Comment: At a given pressure water boils at one temperature (100°C at STP) so it's not clear what you mean by "to boil water at precise temperatures". Can you clarify in your question. Maybe you mean "to heat water to a precise temperature". What is the motor for?

Comment: Yes that is what i meant. i want to make a diy coffee maker that has PID capabilities such as the Rancilio Silvia Espresso Machine

Comment: How are you going to get 1kW of power through those transistors? They would need to be able to source 83Amps. If you have a heater you don't need a negative polarity.

Comment: @cjj887: Put all the relevant information into your question so that it's all in one place. I note that you didn't answer my second question.

Comment: i know that amount of power through transistors is not possible. im asking if there are any other ways of implementing this analog controller or if i would need to use a digital PIC temperature controller.

Comment: i will edit my question... the picture with the motor is just an implementation of this PID controller. instead of controlling the power to the motor, i would want to regulate the power to a boiler

Answer (score 1):

Feed the control output into a PWM with a period of a few seconds and control an SSR (solid-state relay) with it. That's standard practice for industrial temperature control loops. Most likely you will be using mains power for the heater.

Boilers are potentially extremely dangerous, so you need fail-safe measures to ensure an explosion is impossible. At a minimum, I would think, a pressure relief valve and an over-temperature cutout, in addition to the controller, but it's up to you to evaluate all of the safety aspects.

Also note that your PID controller is too simple to work well, it lacks anti-reset windup provisions, so it will tend to overshoot greatly. It also needs to be tuned to the system dynamics (at least two degrees of freedom, and potentially three), or it will almost certainly be sluggish, over/undershoot or oscillate.

Answer (score 0):

The conceptual way to regulate temperature in a boiler using linear analog circuitry is already shown in your picture. This is the classic analog implementation of PID - proportional-integral-differential controller. This is the "best way", theoretically.

However, whether this is the best way to regulate water temperature in your particular coffee machine is an open question. To use the differential part of the regulator you need to specify requirements on how fast do you want your temperature to get to set point, which would require knowledge of thermal mass. To design the integral part you would need to specify the accuracy of control. You elected to omit these specifications that would allow to determine which implementation is "best", and which is not.

More, with linear amplifier stage and 1 kW in load, the transistors will be dissipating another 1 kW, which you will need to conduct away. This doesn't sound any reasonable. Therefore, even if going through analog front-end, the end-stage amplifier must be at least "class-D", using PWM - Pulse-Width-Modulation. Or the transistors should be the actual heating elements.

Also, don't expect your analog form to be easily tuned to be stable, and a lot of experimentation and/or careful analysis of inertial elements of your boiler would be required.

Finally, as one of my co-workers used to say about 40 years ago, "the best analog electronics is the digital one". So drop your unsubstantiated wish of using analog operational amplifiers, and go with a proven digital implementation, which does exactly the same thing but just in a clean algorithmic form. Your hardware will be much smaller, cheaper, and operate more reliably.

But as an educational project, the analog schematics is fine.

Answer (score 0):

A PID is not used for a water heater.  Since the dT/dt ['C/s] is much slower than the rate of power regulation, you only need high gain P control with optional hysteresis. e.g. if tank heats up to 85'C in 340s then it is 0.25 'C/s and power switching uncertainty time is say <0.1s with overshoot <'1C.

The problem is you are thinking a motor servo control is needed to regulate water temperature. Show me one that is relevant.  Your gas or electric water tank will be just on off control for 1'deg error.

The location of the sensor is not important since the heater is immersion.

### MISC.

But if there is no water, the immersion heater will quickly burn out.  So how can you detect if there is water present?

1) sense the heater inlet relative to the tank.
2) detect a rise in heater resistance for a 100'C coil rise above tank  OR
3) use a float or height sensor for tank

[image]

Rancillio's may use an SSR that is optically isolated or simply a Triac with a ZCS opto-coupler for low interference and isolation.

So all you need is a thermistor wheatstone bridge with setting pot and comparator to drive a ZCS opto to drive a 15A Triac with an Op Amp to cheap DMM calibrated in mV/'C